# Rspec have_attributes matcher

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm using Rspec version 3 and I have an issue with have_attributes matcher.

The code I'm testing:

```
   it 'will match class instances with #have_attributes' do
        Person = Struct.new(:name, :age)
         person = Person.new("Jim", 32)

        expect(person).to have_attributes(:name => "Jim", :age => 32)

    end
```

But I got this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(person).to have_attributes(:name => "Jim", :age => 32)

expected #<struct Person name="Jim", age=32> to respond to `has_attributes?`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that the issue was related to Rspec version, I updated the gem from 3.0.1 to 3.3.0 and the issue is solved.